# Where to store the simple data? As example: wishlist

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies

I need to make a pretty easy 'wishlist' for an online-catalog. Because the site has no login system, the wishlist should be available until the user is on the site. I would save some infos as a json string, and because of the amount of products on the page, this wouldn't be too large.

So my question would be, what would be the best solution to store this data?

- PHP Session variable
- Cookies
- localStorage
- DB? (this would be good if we want to use the data later, but in this case what data would be the best to identify the current session?)

Every idea is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need the customer data for some analytics later. So I suggest putting the data into the DB using the current Session ID to identify the current session.

Answer (score 0):

How many space required to store in database? I think it gonna blow up when one user has more than 10 wishlist or even more. Say you have 10.000 users and every user have 20 wishlist. It will required 200.000 records in wishlist table. Accessing this records requires time and high server load.

I think it's better to store them in every user's computer, meaning in cookies. Or better not utilize this tool unless you have a big server and HS internet connection. Not recommended for sharing hosting...